# Why the create method of Javassist ProxyFactory does not invoke the right constructor based on the args parameter?

Tags: java, javassist

Consider the following class declaration:

```
class A{
    private String x;
    public A(String x) {
            this.x = x;
    }
}
```

When I try to create a proxy for the class A with the javassist with the following code:

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
factory.setSuperclass(A.class);
MethodHandler mh = new MethodHandler() {...};
A a = (A) factory.create(new Class<?>[0], new String(){"hello"}, mh);
```

then I got `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: app.test.A_$$_javassist_0.<init>()`

Why javassist does not instantiate the class A using the correct constructor based on the type of the parameters of the second argument passed to the create method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the last statement by:

```
Class proxyKlass = factory.createClass();
Constructor<T> ctor = proxyKlass.getConstructor(String.class);
T res = ctor.newInstance(new String(){"hello"});
((Proxy) res).setHandler(handler);
```

Comment: Yes I understand your approach, but why the `create` method of the `ProxyFactory` does not follow the same solution?

Answer (score 4):

By passing `new Class<?>[0]`, you are telling the factory to call the no-args constructor. Try:

```
factory.create(new Class<?>[] { String.class }, new String[]{ "hello" }, mh);
```